# SQL query to check for certain words in a text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where I need to check for certain words that is being entered in a textbox. I have a table which consists of a list of words. I need a sql query which would check the text for any of the words that is present in this table and return me true / false (or 0 / 1) accordingly. The DB is MS-SQL 2008 and code is in C#

Would be great if anyone could help me with this query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And what scripting language?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table invalidwords(word varchar(10))

insert into invalidwords(word)
values ('ass'),('rascal'),('idiot')

declare @strg varchar(1000) = 'What an asshole'

select *
from invalidwords
where @strg like '%' + word + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split the textbox value by space, then pass them into the `IN()` part of the query

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM words
  WHERE Word in ('foo','bar')
) As Found
```

Remember to sanitize the textbox value to prevent SQL injection, or better yet, use prepared statements.